# como pasar parametro a funcion en label creado dinamicamente?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

Resulta que creo label dinamicamente asi:`
    var contenedor = document.getElementById('contenido3');

```
    for (var i = 0; i <= cantidad; i++) 
    {
        console.log(i);
        var newLabel = document.createElement('label');
        newLabel.className += "lblcuotas";          
        var nroDeCuota =(i+1).toString();
        newLabel.setAttribute("id","cuota"+nroDeCuota);
        var montoCuota= (i+125).toString();
        newLabel.setAttribute("onclick","javascript:selectorCuotas(3);");           
        if (i==0)
        {
            newLabel.innerHTML =nroDeCuota+"   cuota  de  $ "+ montoCuota;
        }
        else{
            newLabel.innerHTML =nroDeCuota+"   cuotas  de  $ "+ montoCuota;
        }

        contenedor.appendChild(newLabel);

    }`
```

necesito pasar el valor de i del for como parametro el momento de crear el evento onclick a cada label con `newLabel.setAttribute("onclick","javascript:selectorCuotas(3);");`

e intentado poniendo "i" pero me dice que i no esta declarada, luego intente con secuencias de escape pero tuve solo errores, desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No hace falta que definas el evento `onclick` con el método `setAttribute`.

Como `newLabel` es de tipo `HTMLElement`, puedes definir un *event listener* directamente del siguiente modo

```
newLabel.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // ...
    // Aquí sí tienes acceso a la variable i
    selectorCuotas(3);
});
```

Espero que sirva.

Comment: excelente si me sirvio, ahora tengo el problema de que siempre que llamo al evento click me llama al ultimo label que creo, osea el ultimo valor de i,seguire investigando, Gracias por el aporte

Comment: Puedes abrir otro post con el nuevo código para verlo. De todas formas, siempre es mejor que uno mismo trate de solucionarlo primero.